# Passing functions as a parameter

Tags: parameter-passing, javascript

How to pass a function to another function and call it in that other script in specific moment? 
For example I would like to do something like this:

```
var interval;   
var parallaxElements = function(elementSet,operacija){
    clearInterval(interval);
    var parallax = [];
    if(elementSet!=null){
        elementSet.find(".parallax").each(function(index) {
            parallax.push($(this));
        }); 
    }   
    parallaxTiming = 30;
    parallax = _.shuffle(parallax);

    interval = setInterval(function(){
        var elem = parallax.shift();        
        if(typeof(elem)!="undefined"){
             elem.stop().transition({
                y: "0px",
                z: "0px",
                duration:"850ms"
             })  
        }else{
            clearInterval(interval);
```

THIS IS WHERE I EXPECT THE PASSED FUNCTION TO BE CALLED

```
            return operacija;
            };          
        }, parallaxTiming); 
    }
```

And then to call the function like this:

```
parallaxElements(container,function(){ alert(123); });
```

Any help will be more then usefull. Thanks in advance for all answers.

Comment: You just have to call it `operacija()`, I don't understand the problem here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `operacija()`.

Little demo code:

```
var foo = function(operacija) {

  interval = setInterval(function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    return operacija();
  }, 1000);
};

foo(function() { alert("123"); } );
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `return operacija;` to `return operacija();`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion You just return the function as a function but not the result of its execution.

Try this:

```
return operacija.call();
```

Comment: [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) requires you to pass the context object as first argument (e.g. `operacija.call(this)`), which you neglect to do; calling a function without needing to specify context does not require a `.call()` invocation, but a simple `operacija()` call, just as @elclanrs and @CyrilleKarmann noted.

Comment: Although it's unusual to use `call` like that, it's not exactly wrong, and does work.